# Bug Reporting Tool pops up everytime I login

Tags: 11.04

I have a dual-boot with XP and 11.04. Everytime I start-up 11.04, bug reporting tool comes up and when I click create report, text file shows as below:

```
System: Linux 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686
X Vendor: The X.Org Foundation
X Vendor Release: 11001000
Selinux: No
Accessibility: Disabled
GTK+ Theme: Ambiance
Icon Theme: ubuntu-mono-dark
GTK+ Modules: gnomesegvhandler, canberra-gtk-module

Memory status: size: 29282304 vsize: 29282304 resident: 7127040 share: 5787648 rss: 7127040 rss_rlim: 18446744073709551615
CPU usage: start_time: 1304253607 rtime: 7 utime: 6 stime: 1 cutime:0 cstime: 0 timeout: 0 it_real_value: 0 frequency: 100



----------- .xsession-errors ---------------------
** (gnome-session:1467): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:1467): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:1467): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:1467): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:1467): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:1467): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:1467): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:1467): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
** (gnome-session:1467): DEBUG: GsmDBusClient: obj_path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus method=NameOwnerChanged
Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
/home/virgil/1977: No such file or directory.
No stack.
--------------------------------------------------
```

The last three or four lines of the above text shows some hint of the problem but I don't understand it. Need help.

Comment: I know it's not a solution to the problem but you could disable the bug reporting tool (Apport).

Comment: @virgil1978, have you actually reported this bug to Launchpad yet?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. This will be closed. If this question is still valid, please add more detail and flag for it to be reopened.